# "Ну(,) а вдруг?" — нужна ли запятая

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли запятая перед "а" в выражении: "**Ну(,) а вдруг?**"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Запятая не нужна**: здесь НУ не междометие, а **частица** в составе устойчивого сочетания  частиц ***"ну а"***.